# XGBoost python: Bad input shape, features name mismatch error

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost, mnist

Binary classifier to predict if a digit is 5 or not has X_train and y_train(and similarly X_test and y_test as follows. (similar to MNIST dataset)

```
X=train_df.drop('label', axis=1)
y=train_df['label']
X_train, X_test, y_train_full, y_test_full = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=66)
#For digit 5, output label=1, for any other digit output label=0
y_train=((y_train_full==5).astype(int))  
y_test=((y_test_full==5).astype(int))
```

X_train

```
pixel0  pixel1  pixel2  pixel3....................pixel783   
 0       1         1      0                        1         
 0       0         0      1                        1
```

y_train

```
 label

  1
  0
```

and so on.

Basically X_train represents the pixels of a digit. y_train represents the label of the digit, for example if the digit is 5, then the label will be 1, if the digit is not 5, the label will be zero.

I implement XGBoost as follows:

```
#from xgboost.xgbclassifier import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
classifier = XGBClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Accuracy on test set:',classifier.score(X_test,y_test))


---->print('Accuracy on test set:',classifier.score(X_test,y_test))

Error: ValueError: feature_names mismatch:
```

Then to remove the features name mismatch, I try below as mentioned in many answers that I should change X_train and y_train to numpy arrays:

```
X_train=train_df.drop('label', axis=1).values
X_test=train_df['label'].values
classifier.fit(X_train,X_test)

----->classifier.fit(X_train,X_test)
Error: ValueError: bad input shape (28000, 784)
```

**What I want:**

I simply want to **fit XGBoost** and calculate its **accuracy score like this on test set:**

```
print('Accuracy on test set:',classifier.score(X_test,y_test))
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: yes.............................